# C# AES decrypted binary file size doubled. Only text files worked fine

Tags: c#, encryption

When encrypting and decrypting text files, the code works fine.

But when encrypting binary and zip files, file size almost doubled after decryption. For example, a 2.06mb bin.exe became 3.69mb after decryption; a 4mb zip file became 7+mb after decryption.

Is this because of the PaddingMode? What PaddingMode should I set to work with all types of files? How to solve this problem?

```
     private async Task RunEncrypt(string srcfile)
     {
        string data;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(srcfile))
        {
            data = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        byte[] enc_data = await Program.myEncrypt(data);
     }


    static async Task<byte[]> myEncrypt(string toEncStr)
    {
        byte[] encrypted;
        using (Aes encaes = Aes.Create())
        {
            try
            {
                //store key to key.txt 
                FileStream fs = new FileStream("key.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                fs.Write(encaes.Key, 0, encaes.Key.Length);
                fs.Write(encaes.IV, 0, encaes.IV.Length);
                fs.Close();
            }
            catch ( Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Recording encryption keys failed!{0}.", e.Message);
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }

            encaes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            ICryptoTransform encryptor = encaes.CreateEncryptor(encaes.Key, encaes.IV);

            try
            {
                using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                        {
                            swEncrypt.Write(toEncStr);
                        }
                    }
                    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                }
                return encrypted;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Encryption failed!{0}.", e.Message);
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("null");
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task RunDecrypt(byte[] inbytes)
    {
        try
        {
            string write_data = await myDecrypt(inbytes);
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("test.exe", true))
            {
                sw.Write(write_data);
                sw.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
    async Task<string> myDecrypt(byte[] toDecBytes)
    {
        try
        {
            string decrypted;
            using (Aes dec = Aes.Create())
            {
                byte[] Key = new byte[dec.Key.Length];
                byte[] IV = new byte[dec.IV.Length];

                //read key from key.txt
                FileStream fsread = new FileStream("key.txt", FileMode.Open);
                fsread.Read(Key, 0, Key.Length);
                fsread.Read(IV, 0, IV.Length);
                fsread.Close();

                dec.Key = Key;
                dec.IV = IV;

                dec.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

                ICryptoTransform decryptor = dec.CreateDecryptor(dec.Key, dec.IV);
                using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(toDecBytes))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                        {
                            decrypted = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                            return decrypted;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Decryption failed! {0}.", e.Message);
            return @"null";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Binary data should be fed to the encryption as binary data, not as binary data that has arbitrarily been converted to UTF8. Stop using a `StreamReader` to convert into strings. Treat files as binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using a StreamReader and StreamWriter, you are treating the file content as text. To support binary files, read/write directly from/to the source/target stream instead.

Comment: Use FileStream instead?

Comment: @MinKim or `MemoryStream` so you can return a `byte[]` instead of a `string`. Also your function `myEncrypt` uses `async` but has no `await` inside of it. It should drop the `async ` and return a `byte[]` instead of a `Task<byte[]>` (or `Task<string>`)

Comment: In that case, I have to change `myEncrypt(string src)` to `myEncrypt(byte[] src)` as well. And also modify  `using (CryptoStream csEncrypt...` block of code. Could you please show me how? I'm newbie to C#

Comment: [link]https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/769741/Csharp-AES-bits-Encryption-Library-with-Salt   this artical really helps me a lot! Just in case anyone else has the same problem. Thanks to all !